# How can I add an item in the World-menu of Pharo 4.0?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

How can I add a new item - Workspace openLabel: 'Workspace' - to the World-menu of Pharo 4.0 ?  (What can I say... I prefer Workspace over the new what's-it-called.  :-)

I've looked at several menu-related items in the Browser, but couldn't really make head or tails of it.  I also tried to find where the menu is stored (it must be somewhere, right?), but couldn't find it.

Also, how would I go about to add it to one of the existing sub-menues of World-menu, and how could I create a new sub-menu (in the World-menu) and add it there?

Comment: I like the new Playground a lot, but I also think for quick scripting the Workspace is the more straightforward tool. The names already suggest very well the different use cases. I think both should be included in the World Menu by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following class method to any class you like. Best to make one especially for this purpose and load it to your new images:

WorkspaceWorldMenuItem class>>menuCommandOn: aBuilder

```
menuCommandOn: aBuilder
<worldMenu>

(aBuilder item: #'Workspace')
    order: 0.1;
    label: 'Workspace';
    action: [ Workspace open ]
```

The interesting part is the `<worldMenu>` pragma. You usually put it directly after the selector (and comment) and before any other element in the method.

To have a look at example usage open *Finder*, choose the *Pragmas* mode and search for `worldMenu` (without the angle brackets).