# How do I load Magritte3 and Seaside 3.0 in Pharo 4.0?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

If you click on the desktop in Pharo 4.0 -> Tools -> Configuration Browser and search for "seaside" you get Seaside 3 and MagritteSeaside both of which install the latest version of everything.

How do I install Magritte 3 andSeaside 3.0(not 3.1) in a freshly downloaded Pharo 4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Configuration Browser instead of installing the stable version select **Load Configuration** button.

Then open a Playground (World > Playground) and execute the following

```
(ConfigurationOfSeaside3 project version: #'release3.0') load
```

If you want a different version, open the class `ConfigurationOfSeaside3` (you can do so by selecting the name and pressing ctrl+b, or via Spotter (shift+enter).

Once opened, select the `symbolic versions` protocol and see what versions are available. You could also load exact patch version such as `3.1.1.3` in the same way, but I strongly advise against it.

[image]

As for MagritteSeaside, it just **loads a specific group** from Magritte, but you can load it directly:

load Configuration of Magritte3 from Configuration Browser in the same way, and execute the following

```
(ConfigurationOfMagritte3 project version: #'release3.0') load: 'Seaside'
```

Comment: It seems it didn't load the Seaside Control Panel in Tools - World. If I click Install Stable in Configuration Browser the Seaside Control Panel is there. Any thoughts?

Comment: @unmircea from a quick digging into the source code it seems that the button was added in version 3.1.2. But adding the button is rather simple https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009023/how-can-i-add-an-item-in-the-world-menu-of-pharo-4-0/31011296#31011296